exam with bullet points for answers
On the back of this question I'd like to replace the formatting for answer-line parts with bullet points. As an added complexity, I'd also like some questions to have parts in the (a), (b) format. I.e.
1. Question in two parts on fruit. 

(a) What is an orange? Give two details. [2 marks]

    •.............................................
     .............................................
    •.............................................
     .............................................

(b) What is a banana? Give three details. [3 marks]

    •.............................................
     .............................................
    •.............................................
     .............................................
    •.............................................
     .............................................

This is as far as I have got with the kind help of @jilab
\documentclass[a4paper]{exam}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

\question[2] Name any two vegetables.
\begin{parts}
  \part \noindent\vspace{-\dottedlinefillheight}
  \fillwithdottedlines{2cm}
  
  \part \noindent\vspace{-\dottedlinefillheight}
  \fillwithdottedlines{2cm}
\end{parts}

\end{questions}

\end{document}


Well, you simply have to generalise the previous answer. You can create a dedicated command for that
\NewDocumentCommand{\fillwithdottedlinesnopar}{ O{0pt} m }
{%
  \noindent\vspace{\dimeval{-\dottedlinefillheight + #1}}%
  \fillwithdottedlines{#2}
}

the optional argument allow you to add an extra space.
Example:
\documentclass[a4paper]{exam}

\NewDocumentCommand{\fillwithdottedlinesnopar}{ O{0pt} m }
{%
  \noindent\vspace{\dimeval{-\dottedlinefillheight + #1}}%
  \fillwithdottedlines{#2}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

\question[2] Name any two vegetables.
  \begin{parts}
    \part \fillwithdottedlinesnopar{2cm}

    \part \fillwithdottedlinesnopar{2cm}
  \end{parts}

\question Question in two parts on fruit.

  \begin{parts}

    \part[2] What is an orange? Give two details.

    \begin{itemize}
    \item \fillwithdottedlinesnopar{2cm}
    \item \fillwithdottedlinesnopar{2cm}
    \end{itemize}

    \part[3] What is a banana? Give three details.

    \begin{itemize}
    \item \fillwithdottedlinesnopar{2cm}
    \item Draw and legend a banana\fillwithdottedlinesnopar[3cm]{1cm}
    \item \fillwithdottedlinesnopar{2cm}
    \end{itemize}

  \end{parts}

\end{questions}

\end{document}



Thanks. I was being stupid trying to alter the automatic part labelling when I should have used itemize... many thanks!
